# Drupal 7:Help on configuring views3 to get related content based on node relationship

Tags: drupal, view

I have two content types in my application:-
Student
Teacher

Teacher-Student has parent child relationship. 
Inside Student there is a node reference field to Teacher which means that when creating a student user needs to provide one or more Teacher's before saving content type.
So one student is related to multiple Teacher here.

Suppose X is a student. Y and Z are teachers of X. Now when I opened the student(X) page then I want to see all the related students in a block who belongs to either (Y or Z) or Both.

Can it be possible using Views UI?Please let me know your suggestion on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. Views UI did the magic with the help of relationship. In this case there will be two relations involved. One from student to Teacher and other relation with teacher to student involving the previous relations. I was searching blindly unless I got the article in Internet about turning on the SQL query in Views which helped me to work more logically. This link helped me:-

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11997/use-of-relationships-joins-in-views

Thanks to all.

Comment: Can you add little more details about the approach you took? I mean the relationships that you added and so on?